# How to derive average when picking largest of a set of 3 instead of 1?

Tags: probability

For a set of numbers [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] which are offered at even odds, we have that the average number is 5.5.  My question is, if you are offered 3 numbers instead of 1, how do you get the average of the largest of 3?  Doing some raw data, I come up with around 7.9.  I don't know how to derive that mathematically.

Edit:
To clarify, for picking a set of 3, each number is even odds but exclusive in that set of 3 only.  Each set after has no dependency on previous sets.

Comment: Do you mean expected value?

Comment: How are you choosing these numbers? With or without replacement?

Comment: With replacement.  Even odds for any number.  The same number can't be in the same set of 3.  But, the next set is not dependent of any previous sets.

Comment: Clarrify: How are you selecting each data set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are chosen independently and uniformly from 
$1, 2, \ldots, n$, the probability that the largest $\le k$ is the probability that all three $\le k$, i.e. $(k/n)^3$.  The probability that the largest is exactly $k$, i.e $\le k$ but not $\le k-1$, is then $(k/n)^3 - ((k-1)/n)^3$.
The expected value of the largest is 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n k \left((k/n)^3 - ((k-1)/n)^3)\right) = \frac{(n+1)(3n-1)}{4n}$$

Note that this is choosing them "with replacement", i.e. it is allowed to have two or three of them equal.  If the choice is done "without replacement", i.e. requiring them all to be distinct, then instead of $(k/n)^3$, the probability that all $\le k$ is $$\left. {k \choose 3}\right/ {n \choose 3} = \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{n(n-1)(n-2)}$$

and the expected value of the largest is

$$\sum_{k=3}^n k  \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)-(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)}{n(n-1)(n-2)} = \frac{3(n+1)}{4}$$